# How to Differentiate Browser Vendor in Chrome Extension API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opera

I have developed a Chrome extension submitted to Chrome store.

And now because Opera supports Chrome extension API, I want to submit it to Opera store.

But some wording is browser specific. How can I detect which browser vendor my extension is running on by chrome extension API methods?

I need this background.js

Comment: Tried and failed: `opr` is not defined unless the extension requests Opera-specific APIs.